# Detect key pressed in text input from onkeydown() inline function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have the following

```
<input name='blah[]' onkeydown="itemKeyDown(this)">
```

Is it possible to detect what key was pressed in the itemKeyDown() function?

I tried the usual approach with:

```
e.keyCode || e.which
```

but it returns undefined.

To note:
I could do it the jQuery way, but I needed to specifically attach the function call in the HTML code (inside the  tags) because I'm dynamically generating a lot of copies of this text field, and this way all fields generated will inherit the function call. I don't want to have to bind a listener to a text field, all are generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like that?

```js
function itemKeyDown(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode || e.which);
}
```

```html
<input name='blah[]' onkeydown="itemKeyDown(event)">
```

Comment: crap, ok now i know why it didnt work. i used "this" in the argument instead of event geesh, thanks man.got it working using itemKeyDown(this,event)

Answer (score 3):

```html
<input name='blah[]' onkeydown="itemKeyDown(this)">
```

this keyword doesn't carry any information about the event onkeydown it represent the  DOM element (input)

to get the event data you should pass event keyword like:

```html
<input name='blah[]' onkeydown="itemKeyDown(event)">

<script>
function itemKeyDown(e)
{
  console.log(e.keyCode)
}

</script>
```